# How to build GTK+ APP for ARM based of Linux platform

Tags: arm, gtk, cross-compiling

Could you help to solve this problem?

I am trying to cross-compile a sample GTK+ application for freescale i.MX-6 arm based processor

i have exported my **Toolchain** path

```
**export PATH=/u02/tools/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/fsl-linaro-toolchain/bin:$PATH**
```

and i am trying to cross-compile the application by using following sequence

```
**arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc  gtk-frameless.c -o frameless `pkg-config --cflags=-I/U02/tools/DOP/imx6/rootfs/usr/include gtk+-2.0` `pkg-config --libs=-L/U02/tools/DOP/imx6/rootfs/usr/lib/ -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0  -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo  -lpango-1.0  -lfontconfig  -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfreetype`**
```

and i am stuck with the following error

**-lgtk-x11-2.0: unknown option
/tmp/ccn3JmIw.o: In function `main':
gtk-frameless.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to`gtk_init'

gtk-frameless.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `gtk_window_new'

gtk-frameless.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show'

gtk-frameless.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `gtk_main'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**

in my case i guess i was unable to specify the path of the libraries correctly..?

Is my guess correct or apart from that am i doing any thing wrong,please guide me, to make it compile or provide links of related documents,so that i can try myself.

Any thing would be helpful.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

> i guess i was unable to specify the path of the libraries correctly..?

Yup. Take a close look at the actual flags you pass. These calls do not actually work (try them and see the results):

```
pkg-config --cflags=-I/U02/tools/DOP/imx6/rootfs/usr/include gtk+-2.0
pkg-config --libs=-L/U02/tools/DOP/imx6/rootfs/usr/lib/ -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0  -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo  -lpango-1.0  -lfontconfig  -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfreetype
```

You've got two basic options: either you use pkg-config like this

```
pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0
pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0
```

which gives you the libraries and headers that your pkg-config knows about...

Or you construct the includes and linker flags by hand to point to the cross-compile target header and library locations.

If you're lucky you may be able to use PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR and PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR env variables to enable the use of pkg-config even for cross-compiling (see pkg-config documentation). Some cross-development environments (say, Yocto/openembedded) will do this for you.

Comment: if am executing the pkg-config --cflags=-I.. and pkg-config --libs=-L.. as you have stated i am getting following error "-lgtk-x11-2.0: unknown option".

Comment: Yeah, those calls don't make any sense: "--cflags" and "--libs" do not take arguments and "-l" is not a pkg-config option at all. See pkg-config documentation